# How to change perl default executable file path in windows?

Tags: perl

Now I'm using Padre IDE. Since I am using that, It uses different perl.exe file to run the code.

But by default perl.exe path is set to C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe. I want to change this path to IDE path. How to change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This path is save in environment variable PATH (Advanced System setting->Advanced->Environment Variables).

Answer (score 0):

The search path is stored in the PATH environment variable.  The path to the IDE version is either missing or comes after 'C:\Perl\bin' in the list.

At the command line, you can view the setting with this command:

```
echo %PATH%
```

If it's just missing, this command will add the one you want to the front of the list:

```
setx PATH "Path\To\IDE\Perl;%PATH%" /m
```

Actually, that should work in any case - nothing should break because of a duplicated entry in the list.